# I have to different data frames. How to find the match and merge the dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning

I have two different data frames which are as shown

```
     df1
     ==================================                              
     KEYWORD                     TICKET
     Burst of bit errors          89814
     sync and stand-by reload     66246
     Port sub-modules modelling   70946
     wires stop passing traffic   60245
     Ignore Net flow              59052


     df2
     ==========================         
     TEXT_DATA
     Burst of bit errors due to
     stop passing traffic
```

which are having partial matching. Please help me on this. here is the piece of code which i developed

```
import pandas as pd

Standard_Data = pd.read_excel('bOOK2.xlsx',usecols=[0,1])

print(Standard_Data)

     #Standard_Data
     ==================================                              
     KEYWORD                     TICKET
     Burst of bit errors          89814
     sync and stand-by reload     66246
     Port sub-modules modelling   70946
     wires stop passing traffic   60245
     Ignore Net flow              59052

keyword_data = Standard_Data['KEYWORD'].values.tolist()

input_data = pd.read_excel('book1.xlsx',usecols=[1])

print(input_data)

     input_data
     ==========================         
     TEXT_DATA
     Burst of bit errors due to
     stop passing traffic

#simply df1 = Standard_Data , df2 = input_Data
sentenced_data = input_data['Text_Data'].values.tolist()

df = pd.DataFrame({'sentenced_data':sentenced_data})

print(df)

df['MATCHED_KEYWORD'] = (df['sentenced_data'].apply(lambda x: [w for i in 
                                      keyword_data
                                      for w in i.split(' ')
                                      if w in (x)]))

df['KEYWORD'] = df['MATCHED_KEYWORD'].apply(','.join)

df['KEYWORD'] = df['KEYWORD'].str.replace(',',' ')

Z = Standard_Data.merge(df,on='KEYWORD',how='right')
print(Z)
```

i'm getting the result like

```
KEYWORD                 TICKET              sentenced_data

Burst of bit errors       NaN        Burst of bit errors due to   
stop passing traffic      NaN        stop passing traffic
```

But my Desired Result should be look like this

```
KEYWORD                           sentenced_data               TICKET
Burst of bit errors               Burst of bit errors due to   89814
wires stop passing traffic        stop passing traffic         66246
```

Please anyone help me on resolving this issue

Comment: Can you paste the sample data above instead of a link to picture, plaese?

Comment: @R.yan I have updated the simple dataframes. Can please take a look on it

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

df is your first dataframe, df1 is the second one

```
res = pd.DataFrame()
for text in df1.TEXT_DATA:
        res = res.append(
              df[df.apply(lambda row: row.KEYWORD in text or
                                    text in row.KEYWORD, axis=1)]
              )
print(res)
```

Output:

```
                      KEYWORD TICKET
0         Burst of bit errors  89814
3  wires stop passing traffic  60245
```

---

Here is another way to do it to get **exactly** the same as your expected output:

```
res = pd.DataFrame(columns=['KEYWORD', 'TICKET', 'sentenced_data']) # create an empty dataframe to store the answer
for text in df1.TEXT_DATA: # loop-through the second dataframe
    bools = df.apply(lambda row: row.KEYWORD in text or text in row.KEYWORD, axis=1) # return a boolean series if KEYWORD contains(by the "in" keyword in python) text or text contains KEYWORD
    if (bools.any()): # filter the df by the boolean series, append it to res, append the text to second column
        res = res.append(df[bools])
        res.iloc[-bools.sum():, 2] = text
res = res[['KEYWORD', 'sentenced_data', 'TICKET']]
print(res)
```

Output:

```
                      KEYWORD              sentenced_data TICKET
0         Burst of bit errors  Burst of bit errors due to  89814
3  wires stop passing traffic        stop passing traffic  60245
```

---

`in` keyword in python would return `True` if two `string` are partially match or 100% match; otherwise it return `False`.

Comment: those two are different dataframes. How you are matching i can't under stand. Can you please explain it clearly

Comment: Sure, I'm adding the comments to my code, just gimme a minute. The keyword of the solution is `in`.

Comment: @SyedJameer Comments are added. Basically, I am doing comparison with `in` keyword twice. Let me know if you still have any question.

Comment: i tried to get the result in different ways. But i'm not getting it. If you don't mine can you please adjust it in my code snippet. Please it would be very helpful

Comment: It's quite hard to fix your code unless to I know what are `Standard_Data` and `input_data `. Can you comment your code above as well?

Comment: thanks for the reply. I have made the changes. look at the code once again. I hope this time you will under stand it clearly. help me in solving this puzzle

Comment: Finally Done Thank you @R.yan